# adding values from a group by

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

SELECT created_time, SUM(score) FROM traineescoretest Group By created_time

Here's my sql query and I'd like to know how to convert it to codeigniter syntax. Ive been searching on it since yesterday but found no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, [Reference](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

```
$this->db->select('created_time, SUM(score) as total_score');
$this->db->from('traineescoretest');
$this->db->group_by('created_time');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$this->db->select($field, false);
        $this->db->from($this->main_table);

        if ($extracond != "") {
            $this->db->where($extracond);
        }

        if ($group_by != "") {
            $this->db->group_by($group_by);
        }

        $list_data = $this->db->get()->result();

$field = "created_time, SUM(score)";
$group_by = "created_time";
```

All In one function to fire a query.